# SQLSRV doesn't fetch all rows

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm using the sqlsrv extension for php and have a problem with fetching the rows from a simple query.
My query is a select which should return 133228 rows but when trying to display the rows I get only 15.
I've searched for an answer but couldn't find a solution and this is my first time using this extension. I've found an answer to a previous question about the same problem but in that case the problem was double calling of sqlsrv_fetch_array, which I don't have for sure.

Here is my query:

```
$sql = 'select * from ViewProduct';
$params = array();
$options = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($dbRemote, $sql, $params, $options);
$count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);

if ($count === false)
    echo "Error in retrieveing row count.";
else
echo $count;

//$rows = array();
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
    echo "<br>";
    //$rows[] = $row;
}
```

As I said the above query returns 15 when should be 133228 rows.

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try by disabling `sqlsrv_num_rows` line and ignoring `$options` (sqlsrv will use default cursor type `SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD`).

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem,
this is my solution for this

```
$data = [];
$result_num = false;
// get rows num if have any
$result_count_res = sqlsrv_query( 
                        $conn, 
                        $query, 
                        [],  
                        [ "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ]
                    );

if( $result_count_res === false) {
    echo "Row count false";
}else{
    // set row num
    $result_num = sqlsrv_num_rows( $result_count_res ); 
} 

if($result_num){

    // run another query to retrive results
    $result_res = sqlsrv_query( 
                $conn, 
                $query, 
                [],  
                [ "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD ]
            );

    if( $result_res === false) {

        // get errors from query
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );

    }else{

        // run through "for" loop to retrive all results
        for($i = 0; $i < $result_num; $i++){
            $data[] = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result_res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

    }   

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $result_res );

}else{
    echo "Row count false";
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you explain how this actually solves the problem? I'm having the same problem. My call to `sqlsrv_num_rows` returns the same wrong number of rows that the loop will return later. So the problem apparently is with `sqlsrv_query`. I don't see how your solution actually fixes that problem.