# PHP query to SQL server database (wordpress)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to communicate to a MSSQL Server database with PHP from a woocommerce website (to fetch data like products, categories etc.). But I get no results, here is my code:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                             "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                             "Database"=>$databaseName); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM eshopItemsTable";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
//uncomment to get some results : $table = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
while( $table = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) { 
    print_r($table);
        
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

with this code it prints nothing. But if I uncomment the line above `while` then I get some results but I dont get all of them (there are ~2000 items in the db but I get something like 10 items without the first one - which is obvious because I already consume the first row). What is the proper way to get all the results?

Comment: The code appears OK (in essence, it matches the example from PHP docs).  Have you tried printing out errors - sqlsrv_errors() - either inside the while loop, or after the while loop, to see if there is actually some kind of error occurring?  Also, if you just print a static string inside the while loop, do you get a result?  (ie. can you confirm whether the while loop is actually occurring, even when you see "no results"?)

Comment: @Craig if I remove the commented line then it seems that it not getting into the while - it doesn't print static words. Also there are no errors printed with sqlsrv_errors()

Comment: it could be a timeout, as you are getting dqata from a remote server.

Comment: Is this the same database your website is running on? Or a different one?

Comment: @Mr.Jo different one

Comment: it looks like a timeout that you could set lazy fetch that sends query requests seperataly.

Comment: @netdev I believe you are fetching data from external system. You are facing typical time out issue. You need to get data into batch. I would recommend to use REST APIs, I don't know whether the system you trying to fetch data from does support it or not. I checked woocommerce does support REST APIs [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/)

Comment: @ChinmayTrivedi unfortunately it doesnt support REST API the external system I have to interract with the DB directly

Answer (score 2):

**Seems something wrong with the while.**

The while is ok, but seems like ends before that he had to.

I've looking for some solutions and this man had the same problem:

[SQLSRV doesn't fetch all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169384/sqlsrv-doesnt-fetch-all-rows)

First of all gets the num of results:

```
$result_num = sqlsrv_num_rows( $result_count_res );
```

And then use a **for** instead of a **while**.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $result_num; $i++){
            $data[] = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result_res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
```

Consider also, a time out. Because you are attacking to another server...

Comment: it looks like its working. The problem is that is not the proper way I guess. But as long it works....

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

if ($stmt !== false) {
    while ($table = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($table);
    }
} else {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: I have to communicate with an external SQL Server database, WP_Query doesn't help

Comment: same thing... I have to use 2 sqlsrv_fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use the tools I already have - in case of WordPress it's `wpdb`. Normally when you use `wpdb` you're fetching from the WordPress databse but in our case we connect to a different database before using its methods:

```
$conn = new wpdb( $uid, $pwd, $databaseName, $serverName );

$results = $conn->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM eshopItemsTable' );
```

This handles the timeout stuff too - normally. Try out by logging out the results and tell me if it works. If yes, I think you can continue working with this.

Comment: the thing is that the external database is MSSQL not mysql so I dont think that I am able to use `wpdb`

Comment: Have you tried it? And please add this is a new requirement to your question...

Comment: @Mr.Jo, it's already there: _I am trying to communicate to a SQL Server database with PHP from a woocommerce website ..._

Comment: So you have tried it out and it don't works - right?

Comment: If you have tried it and it don't works I would create a table `eshopItemsTable` on your WordPress database table. After this I would configure a database job on your MSSQL table which syncs with the table every day. This way you have a much faster way to get the results.

Comment: @Mr.Jo any guidance of how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this code, where you can print errors step by step.

```
$serverName = "(local)";
$uid = "Enter Username";
$pwd = "Enter Password for SQL User";
$databaseName = "Enter name of the Database";
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,
                         "Database"=>$databaseName);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )  
{  
     echo "Could not connect.\n";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}   

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM eshopItemsTable";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
if( $stmt === false)  
{  
     echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
{  
      echo $row['ItemsName'].", ".$row['ItemsPrice']."\n";  
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```